# Note 3 on OSX. Stuck in "Connected as a media device"

Tags: usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-note-3, macos

I'm studying tutorials on Android development. After struggling to get an AVD running on my system, I'm using my personal cell (A Note 3 on Verizon) to test the small programs I'm writing.

I enabled developer options and USB Debugging on my phone. When I connect it to my computer (an iMac running OSX), it behaves as most people want it to: It notifies "Connected as an installer" for ~30 seconds, then displays "Connected as media device." The Android File Transfer application starts up.

My problem: I need it to stay in "Connected as an installer" mode. So long as it's "Connected As Media Device" Eclipse and the Android SDK can't copy programs to it.

For the last few days, simply closing Android File Transfer on the computer caused the phone to revert back to "Connected as an installer". Lately, though, that doesn't do the trick. I open and close Android File Transfer, but the phone is stuck in "Connected as a Media Device" mode.

If it helps: Eclipse can see the device. When I plug it into the USB port, Eclipse's log show all the messages coming off the device. But Eclipse won't run programs on it so long as it's in Media Device mode.

Comment: Weird. Have you checked that USB debugging is enabled?

Comment: "won't run programs" What actually happens?

Comment: aureljared. It's a bit random. Enabling and disabling USB debugging sometimes fixes it, sometimes not.

Comment: Dan Hulme. Eclipse doesn't see the phone as a target when I attempt to run the program.

Comment: I wrote this post last night when I was badly rushed for time. I used only Eclipse's tools and my Note 3. Tonight I'll work directly with the abd program, and I'll see if can borrow my wife's Nexus 7 for troubleshooting. Then I can determine if the problem is with the phone, the SDK, or Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I am a professional Mobile Application Developer, and often use my own personal Galaxy Note 3 for test at the office, and I've never come across this issue.

When I plug my Note 3 into my Mac Pro, it appears connected as a media device, and it appears in the Eclipse "device chooser" window.

What you probably need, is the Android File Transfer software, [which can be downloaded here](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/).

If that doesn't work, try looking for Samsung drivers for OSX, although I don't believe I ever installed any.